# Usage of somearray[i].var() in python

Tags: python

I am completely new to python and trying to debug a code which needs to be re-written in C. This might be a very silly question.
I came across  this statement

```
result[i, j] = arr[i:j+1].var() * (j-i)
```

I  just couldn't find the documentation of this var() method even after googling out. Can some one tell me what exactly does it mean?

Comment: That depends on what the array contains. It's just a method of that type. Use `type(arr[i:j+1])` and search for documentation on that type.

Comment: Assuming it's a `numpy` array, you're probably looking for something like [this](http://pod.tamu.edu/~lmkli/reference/python/numpy_html/reference/generated/numpy.var.html) (except this is a function, not a method).

Comment: **Edited**      "result" is 2d array of floats and "arr" is a 1d array of floats. In the code it is mentioned as x = ['1' 10.6', '10.7' ... ]

Comment: @Nike , please tell us more about what this code you're translating is doing...

Comment: @Nike The built-in lists don't have that function, so I think you're probably setting it with `numpy.array` somewhere. Do you have an `import numpy` anywhere in your file?

Comment: I guess Steven is right. I am trying to translate Fisher Jenks algorithm. Lack of comments makes it a nightmare it understand any code. But as I see the documentation of numpy.var, it needs atleast one argument and in the code I mentioned above, there is no argument. So is it that numpy.var acts on the arr[] array ?

Comment: @Nike Look at my answer. `var` exists as a global function, and also as `ndarray.var`. The one on `ndarray` doesn't have any required parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This is a wild guess, but if that's a [Numpy `ndarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#calculation):

> **ndarray.var([axis, dtype, out, ddof])**     Returns the variance of the array elements, along given axis.

You would create an `ndarray` with something like:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Then `a.var()` would give you the variance.